# Grant execute permission only on files in "bin" subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I have a parent directory that has a number of applications within it, each has its own `bin` subdirectories

```
parent
--app1
  --bin
  --(maybe some other bins on even lower level)
--app2
  --bin
...
```

What I want to do is to add an executable permission on files within `bin` but not on the folder itself.

The structure above is not regular though (so I can't just use a loop to predict that there is a `bin` on a specific depth/level).

So far what I have is this:

```
find /parent -type d -iname "bin" -exec chmod -R a+x {} \;
```

I know there is no harm in doing `chmod -R` on each `bin`, but for the sake of finding a cleaner way, I want to apply the `+x` on the files only.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to allow `x` on the directories: Listing a directory (and thus finding a file within) is what the `x` privilege stands for on a directory.

That said, using

```
-exec chmod -R a+x {}/* \;
```

will assign `x` to only the contents of a dir, not the dir itself.

If you want to cater for nested `bin` directories, use something along the lines of

```
while read F; do \
  test -f "$F" || continue \
  test $(basename $(dirname "$F")) == "bin" || continue \
  chmod a+x "$F" \
done < find /path/to/base -type f
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches:

- As Eugen mentioned, +x on directories is normal – it's even required in order to access the contents. If the scripts are to be world-executable, then it makes sense to continue with your current method and make the directories world-traversable as well.
- You can rely on bash's extended globs to collect all `bin` directories at any depth:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar; find **/bin/ -type f -exec chmod a+x {} \;
  ```

  The same but without type check:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar; chmod -R a+x **/bin/
  ```
- Use multiple `find` calls:

  ```
  find . -type d -name bin | while read -r path; do
      find "$path/" -type f -exec chmod a+x {} \;
  done
  ```

  (This assumes your filenames don't have line-breaks; if they do, you should be worried – and you should adjust the example to use `-print0` and all that.)
- Unfortunately you can't directly nest `find -exec` inside another `find -exec`, but you can call a script that subsequently calls find -exec:

  ```
  find . -type d -name bin -execdir sh -c "find . -type f -exec chmod a+x {} \;" \;
  ```

  This uses `-execdir` instead of `-exec` to avoid troublesome {} nesting.